# How integrate chrome application with extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app

I'm writing an extension.
A part of this extension contains an html page.
I'd call that page, also as a Google Apps,
inserting an icon between applications of chrome.

It's possible create a manifest file to integrate the chrome app with chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd create both an app an an extension, then encourage the user to install both if you detected that one wasn't installed.

There is an outstanding feature request to allow bundled installations of multiple apps/extensions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the issue, so I can star it?

Comment: I also would like to bundle an app and extension together. How do you detect that either is not installed? I can think of some weird ways, but is there a canonical, standard way to do this?